# python exception set cause/stacktrace

Tags: python, exception, runtime-error, simulation, agent

I am writing a platform for agent simulations in python 3.7. A user of the system implements the mind (decision making procedure, belief revision etc) in a python class. An agent attempts an action as follows:

```
import action

class MyMind:

    def decide(self):
        return action.move()
```

`decide` is called by the platform, the action is then validated and executed in an environment.

```
def agent_cycle(self):

    action = self.mind.decide()
    #validate actions
    if action is None:
        raise ActionException("blah blah")

    self.actuator.attempt(action) #attempt in environment
```

The problem is that if an action is invalid, an exception is thrown, the stacktrace is not informative to the user - i.e. it doesn't provided any information about their `decide` implementation. `decide` can be very complex, without any information about it execution path it can be quite difficult to debug. I am wondering if there is a simple way to include `decide` in the stack trace. Of course I understand why it is not in the stack trace, but I want to 'fake' where the exception is raised (or something along those lines).

I have tried to accomplish this through the use of `sys.settrace`, to record stack frames in `decide` and using `inspect` to get the source from frames. I can get quite a nice summary this way similar to `traceback` However it is quite hacky and I am not sure how best to incorporate it into an exception. I feel like there must be an easier way, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you just make `MyMind.decide` raise the exception itself, rather than returning None?

Comment: No because it is written by a user, they can write whatever they want in decide. I am validating what is returned, this is where the exception is thrown - checking if the action is None is just a toy example. The real validation is more sophisticated.

Comment: You couldn’t identify any *part* of `decide`, so why not just identify the class providing the method?

Comment: @DavisHerring I  am not sure I understand what you mean, but the entire class is written by the user.

Comment: @BenedictWilkinsAI: Since it is the return value that is problematic, any “stack trace” would have to indicate the `return` statement (and you wouldn’t know which if there were more than one).  So saying which class (and thus *which* `decide`) is the best you can do, and is easy.

Comment: @DavisHerring It is possible to find which return statement is used by using `sys.setprofile` you can trace the entire execution path - which is what I am currently doing. I suppose what you are saying is that there is no simple (non hacky) way to do this. Thanks for the comment!